# R count number of specific string in data frame

Tags: r, string

Sorry for beginner questions.

I have a data frame(I think, please correct me if I'm wrong here.)

```
data <- read.csv("adult.data", sep=',', header=F)
```

Data is https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data

When data is missing, it just has "?" instead of data. I need to count how much data is missing in each column.

I can count instances of a number, but not strings.

Col 1 is age, so I can do this:

```
length(which(data[,1] == 55))
```

And it will tell me how many people were 55 in this dataset.

But if I try

```
length(which(data[,2] == "?"))
```

It says 0.

How do I compare strings in R?

Comment: And then read the number of ?'s with `sum(is.na(data[, 2]))`

Comment: @RichardScriven Yes, I count eight manually just on the first screen of data in my browser.

Comment: I think there were some leading/lagging spaces.  Should work `library(stringr);sum(str_trim(data[,2])=='?')#[1] 1836`

Comment: @akrun Yeah, that worked. Makes sense, now that I think about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like if you read it in again with `na.strings = "?"` and `strip.white = TRUE`, you'll get proper `NA` values and be able to use `is.na()`

```
df <- read.csv(
    "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data", 
    header = FALSE, 
    na.strings = "?", 
    strip.white = TRUE
)

## total NA in the data
sum(is.na(df))
# [1] 4262

## total NA for column 2
sum(is.na(df[[2]]))
# [1] 1836

## count NA by column
colSums(is.na(df))
#   V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9  V10  V11  V12  V13  V14  V15
#    0 1836    0    0    0    0 1843    0    0    0    0    0    0  583    0
```

Answer (score 2):

Those answerers above were sharp enough to spot the problem "by-eye".  I took the pedestrian route:

```
unique(grep("\\?", df[,2], value = TRUE))
```

that showed me the problem was a space before each of the question marks. Not remembering the na.strings and strip.whitespace options, (thanks for the reminder!) I just:

```
colSums(df == " ?")
```

Now that I see it, reading the data correctly in the first place is obviously the better way.  I only add this to show one way I use to hunt for string data problems when my "eyeball technique" fails me.

Comment: Thanks for the methodology help. Most of my problem was that I don't know R, or how R syntax works, but this kind of approach will help next time.